# ¿Cómo puedo editar el orden de los elementos en un producto en la página de tienda de woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hola a todos como están espero me puedan ayudar con este tema que en verdad no encuentro una solución.

El tema es que necesito cambiar el orden de los ítems de cada producto que se muestra en la página de shop de woocommerce.

Por defecto el orden es:  imagen, nombre de producto, precio, botón.

Y necesito ponerlo en este orden: nombre de producto, imagen, precio botón.

Espero que me puedan guiar. Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: tenes dos opciones: 1) css usando flex o grid podes transformar el table y modificar el order. 2) copias el archivo `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php` a la carpeta de tu child theme `%childthemefolder%/woocommerce/cart/cart.php` y modificas el renderizado del html

Comment: Muchas gracias alo Malbarez, por tu atención, en realidad lo que busco es editar el orden de los elementos de cada producto pero en la lista de la tienda más no en el carrito de compras, me parece una alternativa válida hacerlo con css pero investigando creo que necesito utilizar hoocks para hacerlo.

Answer (score 3):

Para todo lo que es shop, archives y resultados el detalle del producto está en `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php` en ese archivo vas a ver los actions y hooks asociados con sus prioridades.

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content within loops
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

// Ensure visibility.
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
 return;
}
?>
<li <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?>>
 <?php
 /**
  * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
  *
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

 /**
  * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
  *
  * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

 /**
  * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
  *
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

 /**
  * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
  *
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

 /**
  * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
  *
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
 ?>
</li>
```

En tu caso tendrías que remover el `woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail` del `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` y agregarlo al `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` con una prioridad tal que quede luego del nombre ( el title )

En el archivo `functions.php` de tu child-theme/custom-theme:

```
/* sacamos el thumb del pre title */
remove_action(
  'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',
  'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail',
  10
);

/* lo metemos en el title luego del nombre */
add_action(
  'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title',
  'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail',
  15
);

/* opcionalmente movemos tambien la etiqueta "SALE"  */

remove_action(
  'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',
  'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash',
  10
);

/* lo metemos en el title luego del nombre y el thumb */
add_action(
  'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title',
  'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash',
  20
);
```